# Alexa Skills Kit: Asking the user in the middle of an intent, and then continuing within the scope of the same intent, based on user response?

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I know the title might be confusing, so I'll give an example.

```
'GetDataIntent': function(){

    var body = "";
    var url = "someAPI.com";

    https.get(url, (response) =>{
        response.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body+=chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', (chunk) => {
            var data = JSON.parse(body);
            /* Do Some Stuff */


            this.emit(":ask", "Would you like more info?");

            //The Concept I am trying to describe
            Alexa.registerHandlers(innerHandlers);
            var innerHandlers = {
                'AMAZON.YesIntent': function(){
                     this.emit(":tell", "More info");
                     /* then destroy the temp handlers */
                 },
                'AMAZON.NoIntent': function(){
                     this.emit(":tell", "Goodbye!");
                     /* Destroy the temp handlers */
                 }
            };
        }); 
});
}
```

From the documentation I have read about ASK, it seems that you would have to register handlers at the beginning of the program, but for obvious reasons I cant do this. I want to be able to make temporary handlers, similar to the way I have shown, so it does not jump to any random intent, but stays within the scope of the current intent, based on user response.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this inside your endpoint handler, and keep a state on the session object